# What is the order of importance of 重大 重要 大切 大事

Tags: pragmatics

What is the difference in order of importance and contextual usage of the following:

重大 重要 大切 大事

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I checked with a native on this and received the following reply, which I would concur with:

- 重大 is definitely at the top as the most serious
- 重要 is next
- 大切 and 大事 are basically the same and are the most ゆるい of the set.

I hope that helps.